# Unable to generate Pie Chart in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-charting

I want to have a chart created using Apex. Below is the Object parameters:
Pie chart should have Product types shown based on the total quantity of that particular product.

> ProductType__c   QuantitySold__c
>
> A                    10
>
> B                    20
>
> A                    30
>
> C                    25
>
> C                    30

My Apex Code  is :

```
public class AFS {

public class Data 
    {  
    String name { get; set; }   
    public Integer data1 { get; set; }    
    public Data(String name, Integer data1)
     {    
       this.name = name;     
      this.data1 = data1;  
    } 
    }  

     public List<Data> getChartData()
     {      
         List<AggregateResult> arList = [SELECT Revenue__c.ProductType__c PT, SUM(Revenue__c.QuantitySold__c) sum from Revenue__c GROUP BY Revenue__c.ProductType__c];  
         List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();      

      for (AggregateResult ar : arList)
     {   
      String name = String.ValueOf(ar.get('PT'));;
      Integer data1 = Integer.ValueOf(ar.get('sum')); 
      dataList.add(new Data(name, data1));
    }  

       return dataList;


     } 

}
```

VisualForce Code is :

```
<apex:page controller="AFS">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Quantity sold per product">
   <apex:chart height="350" width="450" data="{!chartData}">
    <apex:pieSeries dataField="data1" labelField="name"/>
    <apex:legend position="right"/>
    </apex:chart>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

The Output only shows the below line :

Quantity sold per product

I am unable to find out a feasible solution to this problem. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance ... !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code with Quantity data and it is generating the chart. Please update your Query and it should work.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="AFS">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Quantity sold per product">
            <apex:chart height="350" width="450" data="{!chartData}">
                <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name"/>
                <apex:legend position="right"/>
            </apex:chart>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class AFS {

    public class Data {
        String name {get;set;}
        public Integer data {get;set;}

        public Data(String name, Integer data) {
            this.name = name;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public List < Data > getChartData() {
        List < AggregateResult > arList = [SELECT Account.Name PT, MAX(Amount) sum FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Account.Name];
        List < Data > dataList = new List < Data > ();

        for (AggregateResult ar: arList) {
            String name = String.ValueOf(ar.get('PT'));
            Integer data = Integer.ValueOf(ar.get('sum'));
            dataList.add(new Data(name, data));
        }
        return dataList;

    }

}
```